# AngularJS ng-repeat Handle Overflow of content from one div to another div

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div class="page1" style="height:200px">

    <p>TLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam neque elit, volutpat sed felis id, commodo bibendum nibh. </p>

    <ol>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    </ol>
    <ol start="3">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <span ng-show="item.Display">{{item.Text}}</span>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>

<div class="page2" style="height:200px">

</div>
```

I was trying to move the overflowing content of the first div to the second div.

The first div has static content and dynamic content will be added to it by looping through the array Items via ng-repeat. lets say I have 10 items in the array, I can only display 4 of them in the first div, I want to move rest of the 6 items to the next div.

I know it can be done in jquery, but i have it implemented in angularjs and not sure how to do it there.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: it is not clear. Will you please elaborate more  ?

Comment: angularjs contains jqlite and you can always add jquery full if you want. If it can be done in Jquery, then the same code can be done in Angularjs. I'm not sure what it is you want to do though

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P7Dfz/4/ I want to try the same but with lists, and in angularjs. I do have Jquery included in my project but I cannot use height() though.